# wrong font on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

i have Source Sans Pro in my stylesheets everywhere, i just realized that it's showing Sans Serif on the computer that doesn't have Source Sans Pro installed. but it's showing the correct font on the computer that has the font installed.

so the font has to be installed on the person's computer for it to show? i was hoping it will show up whether the person has it or not.

here's the site, you can see for yourself.
booomchik.com, everything should be Source Sans Pro, headers, text, buttons, everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case someone needs this.
i was adding this in the wrong place, i was putting it at the beginning of styles.css, but it was supposed to go in Magento in System, Configuration, (General section) Design, (HTML Head section) Miscellaneous Scripts.

there might be a different way to achieve this but putting this line in that box worked (i got this line from Google Fonts).

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not Magento question, should be asked in SO site. Most likely this qst will be closed.

You'r css should have the right url of the font to be able to allow browser to load it for you.

Means, you must have font in your server and properly linked via css. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585186/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-on-a-website)

I am not sure how you have used the font in your css.

You can also use google font in to your site instead. 
Check this link:

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#null

Comment: why is this not a magento question? because it happens elsewhere as well?

Comment: Because, it is related to css not magento code. This site is dedicated to Magento. You should ask non magento qst in stackoverflow.com.

Comment: i had the issue in my magento store so i thought this would be the place for it. but ok

Comment: i've tried everything they suggest, still same issue. 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source-Sans-Pro">
  
@font-face{
    font-family: "Source-Sans-Pro";
    src: url('Source-Sans-Pro.ttf'),
    url('Source-Sans-Pro-Bold.eot'); /* IE */
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);

html {
 font-family: "Source-Sans-Pro";
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}

Comment: source sans pro is google font, i don't need to have it on my server (i did try copying it, didn't help). i should be able to just put the @import... and use it. but it's not being recognized still.

Comment: If you are using "Source Sans Pro" from google then you have to have this code: `<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` and then you can change this font in your site.

Comment: nope, still no. thank you for trying though.